# copying data (packet payload) received over a network

Tags: c, string, network-programming

I have an application that receives packets over a network. I am able to interpret all the field value except the payload (data) section.

consider a packet structure:
src addr | src port | dest addr | dest port | data | checksum

the packet itself is stored as a char* and i can get all the values src/des addr, port. But the payload section confuses me. I am able to print it in hex format but printing it in char gives non-ascii value. When i copy the payload section to a new string and print the new string i get nothing i.e. it dost print anything and its length is 0. I don get any error or warning. Could some one pls tell where i am going wrong? I think im missing something here.

Here is the section of code:

```
  typedef struct pcap_802_15_4_s{
   guint16 fcf;
   unsigned char seqno;
   guint16 dpan;
   guint16 daddr;
   guint16 saddr;
   char *payload_data;  
  } pcap_802_15_4_t;


char *packet = read_serial_packet(src, &len);


      if (!packet)
    exit(0);
      else if (packet[0] != TOS_SERIAL_802_15_4_ID) {
    printf("bad packet (serial type is %02x, not %02x)\n", packet[0], TOS_SERIAL_802_15_4_ID);
      }

      plen = packet[1];
      printf("Received packet of length %i: \n", plen);
      if (plen != len) {
    printf("Packet format error: read packet length (%hhx) is different than expected from frame (%hhx).\n", plen, len);
      }

      struct timeval tv;    
      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);


      i = 2;
      // Read in FCF and i+=2
      fcf = packet[i+1] << 8 | packet[i];
      packet_802_15_4.fcf = fcf;
      i += 2;


      {
    if ((fcf & 0x7) == 0x01) {
      printf("  Frame type: data\n");
    }
    else if ((fcf & 0x7) == 0x02) {
      printf("  Frame type: acknowledgement\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("  Frame type: other\n");
    }

    printf("  Security: %s\n", (fcf & (1 << 3)) ? "enabled":"disabled");
    printf("  Frame pending: %s\n", (fcf & (1 << 4)) ? "yes":"no");
    printf("  Ack request: %s\n", (fcf & (1 << 5)) ? "yes":"no");
    printf("  Intra-PAN: %s\n", (fcf & (1 << 6)) ? "yes":"no");
    intraPan = (fcf & (1 << 6));
      }


      {
    unsigned char seqno = packet[i++];
    packet_802_15_4.seqno = seqno;
    printf("  Sequence number: 0x%hhx\n", seqno);
    printf("  Sequence number(dump): 0x%hhx\n", packet_802_15_4.seqno);

      }

      {
    char addrLen = (fcf >> 10) & 0x3;
    short saddr = 0;
    long long laddr = 0;

    // 16- and 64-bit destinations have a PAN ID
    if (addrLen == 2 || addrLen == 3) { 
      short destPan = packet[i++] << 8 | packet[i++];
      packet_802_15_4.dpan = destPan;
      printf("  Destination PAN: 0x%02hx\n", destPan);
      printf("  Destination PAN (dump): 0x%02hx\n", packet_802_15_4.dpan);
    }

    switch (addrLen) {
    case 0:
      printf("  Destination address: none\n");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("  Destination address: invalid? (0x01)\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      saddr =  (packet[i] << 8 | packet[i+1]);
      i += 2;
      packet_802_15_4.daddr = saddr;
      printf("  Destination address: 0x%04hx\n", saddr);
      printf("  case 2: Destination address(dump): 0x%04hx\n", packet_802_15_4.daddr);
      break;
    case 3: {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        laddr = laddr << 8;
        laddr |= packet[i++];
      }
      packet_802_15_4.daddr = saddr;
      printf("  Destination address: 0x%016llx\n", laddr);
      printf("  case 3: Destination address(dump): 0x%016llx\n", (long long unsigned int)packet_802_15_4.daddr);
      break;
    }
    default:
      printf("  Destination address: parse serror\n");
    }
      }


      {
    char addrLen = (fcf >> 14) & 0x3;
    short saddr = 0;
    long long laddr = 0;

    if (!intraPan) { // Intra-PAN packet
      short srcPan = packet[i] << 8 | packet[i+1];
      //packet_802_15_4.span = srcPan;
      i += 2;
      printf("  Source PAN: 0x%02hx\n", srcPan);
    }

    switch (addrLen) {
    case 0:
      printf("  Source address: none\n");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("  Source address: invalid? (0x01)\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      saddr =  (packet[i] << 8 | packet[i + 1]);
      packet_802_15_4.saddr = saddr;
      i += 2;
      printf("  case(2): Source address: 0x%04hx\n", saddr);
      break;
    case 3: {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        laddr = laddr << 8;
        laddr |= packet[i++];
      }
      printf("  case(3): Source address: 0x%016llx\n", laddr);
      packet_802_15_4.saddr = saddr;
      break;
    }
    default:
      printf("  Source address: parse serror\n");
    }
      }

      if (iframes) {
    printf("  I-Frame: %s\n", (packet[i++] == 0x3f)? "yes":"no");
      }

      printf("  AM type: 0x%02hhx\n", packet[i++]);

      if (i >= plen) {
    printf("Packet format error: read packet is shorter than expected.\n");
      }
      else {
        int j=0;
    packet_802_15_4.payload_data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (plen - i));
    for (; i < plen; i++) {
      printf("Payload byte %d: 0x%02hhx \n",i,packet[i]);
      printf("Payload byte %d: %c \n",i,packet[i]);
      packet_802_15_4.payload_data[j] = (char) packet[i];
      j++;  
    }
```

The Hex output of payload: 
0x00 
0x01 
0x10 
0xdd

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to treat the payload as a string, when it might be binary data. What does your hex version of the payload look like?

Comment: payload in hex : 0x00  0x01  0x10  0xdd

Comment: What are you expecting the payload to be?

Comment: it is a counter with value incremented for every packet

Comment: Sounds like trying to print the value with %c makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have a Wireshark, capture several packets and check the payload representation there. If Wireshark displays your payload right, then receiver part of the code must be problematic.

2) Are you sure you don't have any IP header or TCP header? Are you transferring raw ethernet?

3) Are you sure the payload is nothing but the characters?

Comment: this is not an IP packet. this is IEEE 802.15.4 and the packet structure is a rough one. i have altered some fields to keep it simple.

Comment: could you have a scenario where you always transfer same string + all 0 padding? so, maybe if you have a bug in parsing the packet, you may solve the indexing+offset issues by matching the ascii? let say you are sending all character 'AAAAA'+zero padding, then you must see 0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41 ....

Comment: Also Wireshark doesnt dissect the Am abstraction layer in TinyOS 802.15.4 frame. So could not check with it.

Comment: i dont think there is any indexing issue since all the fields are fixed length (1 byte) values except the address which are 2 byte in length. Also the payload being sent is constant sized (4 bytes).

Comment: then, without seeing how it is serialized or how you parse the payload, it is hard to proceed with what we have.

Comment: im sorry, thought i have done some obvious mistake. have posted the concerned code now